# Hello, can I ask some questions about java(Abstract, getter,setter)?

Tags: java

I have some trouble...
I want to get information at the "Science" and "Children" class.
But my result like that

Science Book: `title= null`, `ISBN = null`, `Publisher= null`, `Price= null`, and `Year= null`

How can I fix and show information?

At first, it is an abstract class, the name is Book

```java
String title;
String ISBN;
String publisher;
double price;
int year;

public String toString() {
    return "title ="+title+" "+"ISBN ="+ISBN+" "+"Publisher= "+publisher+" "+"Price= "+price+" "+"Year= "+year+" ";
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return ISBN;
}

public void setIsbn(String ISBN) {
    this.ISBN = ISBN;
}

public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}

public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public void getBookInfo() {

}

public abstract double setPrice(double price);
```

```java
class ScienceBook extends Book {    

    public double setPrice(double price){

        return price*0.1;
    }

    public void setBookInfo() {

        title = "sbook1";
        ISBN =  "123456";
        publisher = "pub2";
        year = 2017;
        price = 10;

    }
}
```

```java
class ChildrenBook extends Book{

    public double setPrice(double price) {

        return 20;
    }

    public void setBookInfo() {

        title = "cbook1";
        ISBN =  "12345";
        publisher = "pub1";
        year = 2016;
        price = 20; 
    }   
}
```

Program execution will start from here,

```java
public class Midtermtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ScienceBook scb1 = new ScienceBook();
        ScienceBook scb2 = new ScienceBook();
        ChildrenBook chb = new ChildrenBook();


        System.out.println("Here is the book information: ");

        System.out.println("Science Book: "+scb1.toString());
        System.out.println("Children Book: "+scb2.toString());
        System.out.println("Childern Book: "+chb.toString());
    }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Science Book: title= () ISBN = () Publisher= () Price= () Year= ()

Children Book1 ~~

Children Book2 ~~

() << they are information
```

Comment: you havent called `scb1.setBookInfo(); scb2.setBookInfo(); chb.setBookInfo();`

or you can make it as constructor

Comment: Basically when you design a class get Mandatory state info via the constructor and provide setters for optional states, since you have set the state info, it is behaving like that

Comment: You generally don't want a book to exist without a title or piblisher. That's where constructors are for. [See here for more details](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/constructors-in-java/).

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong with your code:

1. You never set any information for your books.
   You have methods to do it `setBookInfo`, but you never call them in your code, so they never run.

By default, all member variables (that are not primitives) in Java are set to `null` if you do not explicitly initialize them.

2. Your `setPrice` function does not set the price.
   It returns some integer value, but does not change the `price` member field of the object.
3. In your `setPrice` the parameter name `price` is the same as instance member `price`.
   This will cause what is called "overshadowing": if you write `price = 20` in that function, you will be changing the parameter (only locally, in that function), not the `private int price` member.
   To access the member variable, you will have to address it specifically by using `this.price` or just change the name of your parameter.
4. Why do you have the `price` parameter to `setPrice` if you are not using it?
   You should not define unneeded parameters. Use it or remove it.
   This is specially important for homework assignments as it will reduce your grade!

Answer (score -1):

```java
public double setPrice(double price) {

    this.price = 20;
}

public void setBookInfo() {

    this.title = "cbook1";
    this.ISBN =  "12345";
    this.publisher = "pub1";
    this.year = 2016;
    this.price = 20; 
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why - that would make the answer much more useful